# Recreating vocabulary and term pages by using views

Tags: 7, views, taxonomy-terms, entities

Let's say I have a vocabulary named "Gallery" and terms inside of it: "One", "Two" and "Three".

Every term have a image field.

What I would like to accomplish:

After going to mysite.com/gallery I would like to have a custom view with grid of images of all terms from specific vocabulary. After clicking an image I would like to be redirected to mysite.com/gallery/[term-name] where I would have another view that would show a grid of specific fields from nodes related to this term.

I think it has something to do with contextual filters? But I'm not sure if it is possible to relate two views that way (so one would have path "/gallery" and other "/gallery/%" and one would dynamically create paths for the other), is it? :/

How would you approach a problem? Even if views wouldn't be valid solution.

PS. The main problem I'm struggling with now is to create a links in one view (/gallery) to other view (/gallery/%) :/ .

Regards!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to create a views Taxonomy terms, add fields in this order: **Taxonomy term: Term ID (Term ID)** (enable Exclude from display, Thousands marker None), **Taxonomy term: Name** (uncheck "Link this field to its taxonomy term page" option, open "SHOW REWRITE RESULTS" fieldset, enable **Output this field as a link**, in **Link path** enter gallery/[tid]), this is solution for your PS.

Comment: Thanks! I totally forgot that when I'm adding a field, I'm getting additional replacement patterns >_< . I feel it will take a long time when I will use to that all :d .